# Use of word "any" vs "for all" in group theory

Tags: group-theory, soft-question

I am confused between the usage of two words *for all* and *any*. Let us consider the example of the definition normal subgroups, A subgroup $H$ is said to be normal if $\forall g \in G, g^{-1}Hg = H$ but if I rephrase the definition of normal subgroup to $H$ is normal in $G$ if for any $g \in G, g^{-1}Hg = H$.

Are these two definitions correct?

Comment: Something I use to do to check would be to negate and see if the negations are the same. In both cases, to prove the negation you would need to find some g in G such that g^-1 H g was not equal to H

Comment: The word "any" is notoriously ambiguous, and it is a good idea to avoid using it in mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Yeap, if something is true "for any" that means it does not matter which of them you take, which means it is true "for all".

Comment: I suspect “...that means it does not **matter** [rather than mean] which of them you take...” ?

Answer (score 2):

That is how the word "any" is commonly used in mathematics. However, in many contexts, especially outside mathematics, "any" means "some". For instance, "If you are carrying any items on the following list, you must declare them." I usually avoid the word "any" in mathematics because of such potential ambiguity.